# Want to bring events to show on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, angular11

I use fullcalendar-Angular (*angular 11 , fullcalendar 5.5.0*).

But I cannot retrieve events to show on the calendar.

I retrieve events in the picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdAGJ.png

*This is the fetch code.*

```
   
   this.Studio.getStudioCalendar().subscribe(data => {
        data["data"].map((list) => {
              this.eventDateSet.push(list);
           });
           this.calendarOptions;
           console.log("calendar data :",this.eventDateSet)
           console.log("calendarOptions  :",this.calendarOptions)
   })
 }
```

*This is the libar FullCalendar’s  code.*

```
    dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this),
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek,prevYear,nextYear",
    },
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    weekends: true,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    dayHeaderFormat: {
      weekday: "short",
      month: "numeric",
      day: "numeric",
      omitCommas: true,
    },
    buttonText: {
      today: "วันนี้",
      month: "เดือน",
      week: "สัปดาห์",
      day: "วัน",
      list: "กำหนดการ",
    },
    locale: "th",
   events: [this.eventDateSet],
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try with the `initialEvents` property of your `CalendarOptions`.

Also, your events should be of type `EventInput` which doesn't contain a `dateStart` or `dateEnd` property but just `start` and `end`.